# Model on itemview is not shown

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am having a trouble displaying the model in an itemview.
Currently using require.js with backbone.marionette.

this is my header template:

```
// header.js  
define( [
   "jquery",
   "underscore",
   "marionette",
   "user",
   "userSession",
   "text!../../tpl/header_template.html"
   ], function ( $, _, Marionette, User, UserSession, HeaderTemplate ) {

  return Marionette.ItemView.extend( {        
     template: HeaderTemplate,

     initialize: function(){
        alert(UserSession.firstName + " " + UserSession.lastName)
     },

     onRender: function(){
        alert(UserSession.firstName + " " + UserSession.lastName)
     },

     model: new User({
        lastName: UserSession.lastName, 
        firstName: UserSession.firstName
        })
    });
  });
```

this is the template snippet code

```
   Logged in as <%= firstName %> <%= lastName %>
```

and this the code when I try to display the itemview

```
// attached the view
layout.header.show(new HeaderView());
```

When I run this code, the view is rendered fine, but the model (firstname and lastname) data is not correct. firstname and lastname are both null. The weird thing is both on initialize and onRender, they both display the first name and last name correctly.

Does anyone know how to overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should do like:

```
initialize: function(){

    this.model = new User({
        lastName: UserSession.lastName, 
        firstName: UserSession.firstName
    });
}
```

Comment: wow! thanks! been hours trying to solve this, because I though the model would be directly attached without having to set it implicitly.

Comment: You could also pass the model as reference when you create the view: `layout.header.show(new HeaderView(model: UserModel));`

Comment: good catch ingro. fwiw, the original code fails for the same reason you don't specify `el: $("#whatever")` in a view: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/11/09/backbone-js-object-literals-views-events-jquery-and-el/